# How to correctly use abstract and virtual methods?

Tags: c#, architecture, virtual, abstract, software-design

I am trying to use virtual and abstract methods to make my game architecture better.
I'm using C# and Unity for this example.

I use a ShipComponent as a base Class  because I want all the child classes to do the same thing.
But sometimes I want a certain ShipComponent to do something else.

The code will make it a lot clearer:

ShipComponent.cs:

```
public abstract class ShipComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] public ShipControl shipControl;
    public virtual void Init(ShipControl control)
    {
        this.shipControl = control;
    }
    public virtual void IsPlayer()
    {
        SetListeners();
    }


    public abstract void IsNotPlayer();

    public abstract void ReEnable();

    public abstract void SetListeners();
}
```

One of the many child classes that inherits from ShipComponent:

```
public class Rudder : ShipComponent
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    public Transform rudder;

    [Header("Debug Info")]
    [SerializeField] float rudderSpeed;
    [SerializeField][Range(-45, 45)] int setRudderAngle = 0;
    [SerializeField][Range(-45f, 45f)] float realRudderAngle = 0f;

    public override void Init(ShipControl shipControl)
    {
        base.Init(shipControl);

        rudder = transform.GetChild(0).GetChild(4);
        StartCoroutine(SmoothRudderChange());

        SetListeners();
    }
    public override void IsPlayer()
    {
        base.IsPlayer();
    }

    public override void IsNotPlayer()
    {
        PlayerShipControl.OnRudderChange -= SetRudder;
    }

    public override void ReEnable()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SmoothRudderChange());

        SetListeners();
    }

    public override void SetListeners()
    {
        PlayerShipControl.OnRudderChange -= SetRudder;
        if (!shipControl.shipWrapper.ship.IsPlayer) return;
        PlayerShipControl.OnRudderChange += SetRudder;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerShipControl.OnRudderChange -= SetRudder;
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }
```

The main draw back I experience with this, is that I have to copy paste all 5 or 6 methods everytime I create a new ShipComponent class.

It seems messy and theres a lot of repeating code, most of the time the only difference in each ShipComponent is the SetListeners part, and StartCoroutines if any.

Is there a way to dynamically set delegate listeners up?

So I could set them in the base class ShipComponent?

Instead of setting each component individually?

Another script that inherits from ShipComponent for completeness:

```
public class Guns : ShipComponent
{
    IEnumerator mouseAimCycle;

    public override void Init(ShipControl shipControl)
    {
        base.Init(shipControl);

        InitCannons();

        SetListeners();
    }

    public override void ReEnable()
    {
        SetListeners();
    }
    public override void IsPlayer()
    {
        base.IsPlayer();

        mouseAimCycle = AimCycle();
        StartCoroutine(mouseAimCycle);

        SetListeners();
    }

    public override void SetListeners()
    {
        PlayerShipControl.OnFireGuns -= TryFire;
        if (!shipControl.shipWrapper.ship.IsPlayer) return;
        PlayerShipControl.OnFireGuns += TryFire;
    }
    public override void IsNotPlayer()
    {

        StopCoroutine(mouseAimCycle);
        PlayerShipControl.OnFireGuns -= TryFire;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerShipControl.OnFireGuns -= TryFire;
        StopAllCoroutines();
    }
```

Calling the ShipComponent virtual and abstract methods:

```
public class ShipControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Contains Ship + Cargo + Crew and a ref to this ShipControl
    public ShipWrapper shipWrapper { get; private set; }

    ShipComponent[] shipComponents;

    // Gather all ShipComponents and Initialize them.
    public void Start()
    {
        shipComponents = transform.GetComponents<ShipComponent>();
        foreach (ShipComponent comp in shipComponents)
        {
            comp.Init(this);
        }
    }
    // Call this to check if this is players current ship and set the components accordingly.
    public void UpdateIsPlayer()
    {
        if (!shipWrapper.ship.IsPlayer)
            foreach (ShipComponent component in shipComponents)
                component.IsNotPlayer();

        else
            foreach (ShipComponent component in shipComponents)
                component.IsPlayer();
    }
```

And PlayerShipControl, which I use for input, broadcasting the input through delegates, and the theory is that only the **players currently controlled ship** will be listening for this input:

```
public class PlayerShipControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<Transform> SetCamToPlayerShip;
    public static event Action SetShipPanelUI;
    public static event Action<bool> ToggleAnchorIcon, ToggleFlagIcon, ToggleAutofireIcon, ToggleBoatsIcon;

    public static event Action OnFireGuns;
    public static event Action<int> OnRudderChange;
    public static event Action<int> OnSailStateChange;
    public static event Action<bool> OnAllAnchorsCommand;
    public static event Action<bool> OnAllBoatsCommand;


    bool anchor, flag, autofire, boats;

    ShipControl shipControl;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))      // Raise Sails      SailState++
        {
            OnSailStateChange?.Invoke(1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.S))      // Furl Sails       SailState--
        {
            OnSailStateChange?.Invoke(-1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            OnRudderChange?.Invoke(1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            OnRudderChange?.Invoke(-1);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.M))
        {
            OnRudderChange?.Invoke(0);
        }

        // Drop All Anchors
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
        {
            anchor = true;
            ToggleAnchorIcon?.Invoke(anchor);

            OnAllAnchorsCommand?.Invoke(anchor);
        }

        // Haul All Anchors
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.H))
        {
            anchor = false;
            ToggleAnchorIcon?.Invoke(anchor);

            OnAllAnchorsCommand?.Invoke(anchor);
        }

        // Drop All Boats
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.B))
        {
            boats = true;
            ToggleBoatsIcon?.Invoke(boats);

            OnAllBoatsCommand?.Invoke(boats);
        }
        // Take In All Boats
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.U))
        {
            OnAllBoatsCommand?.Invoke(false);

            // TO DO When all boats are back on deck, boatIcon + boatsBoolFlag should be turned off again.
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            OnFireGuns?.Invoke();
        }
    }


}
```

Its a long string of scripts sometimes though so I have left out all the managers and such.

`Ship ship` inside `shipWrapper.ship` is a custom data class that stores the info about the ship, not a Monobehaviour, but it holds a `bool` called `IsPlayer` aswell. Nothing else of interest I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

> The main draw back I experience with this, is that I have to copy paste all 5 or 6 methods every time I create a new ShipComponent class. It seems messy and there's a lot of repeating code, most of the time the only difference in each ShipComponent is the SetListeners part, and StartCoroutines if any.

In the show example you have more differences between implementations then ones described. Without seeing the full code it is hard to suggest something meaningful.

Few notes on the current code:

1. In `Rudder` you don't need to specify `IsPlayer` because the following:

   ```cs
   public override void IsPlayer()
   {
       base.IsPlayer();
   }
   ```

   does not add anything extra, so you can just skip implementation in the derived class.
2. Based on provided examples it seems that `ReEnable` can be defined as virtual in base class with default implementation set to calling `SetListeners` (the same approach as you have with `Init` and `IsPlayer`).
3. `PlayerShipControl.Update` possibly can be improved by moving handlers to dictionary. Something along this lines:

   ```cs
   public class PlayerShipControl : MonoBehaviour
   {
       // ...
       Dictionary<KeyCode, Action> keyActions = new() // not sure about the type
       {
           { KeyCode.W, () => OnSailStateChange?.Invoke(1) },
           // ...
           { KeyCode.V, () =>
               {
                   anchor = true;
                   ToggleAnchorIcon?.Invoke(anchor);
                   OnAllAnchorsCommand?.Invoke(anchor);
               }
           },
           // ...
       };

       void Update()
       {
           foreach (var kvp in keyActions)
           {
               if (Input.GetKeyUp(kvp.Key))
               {
                   kvp.Value();
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```